# How can you access your router via IPV6?

Tags: networking, ipv6

Okay, first I wanted to do this just for the lulz, now it is a matter of principle because I need to understand it.

[My Router](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedport) supports simultaneous IPV4 and V6. For thus, I have 2 default gateways:

```
192.168.2.1
fe80::1%11
```

However, I can only access my routers configuration page via the V4 address, not the V6 one.

[image]

How do I access this page via the V6 address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fe80::` address is a link-local address. It needs the scope (interface) id appended to it, which in your case is `%11`. Unfortunately many browsers don't support specifying the scope id in the URL. Older versions of Firefox used to accept it, but the current implementation is broken.

To access your router with a browser using IPv6 you'll need to find out which 'normal' (global scope) addresses it has. Those addresses don't need a scope id and will work in your browser.

When you find a usable IPv6 address then you can use it in a URL. Because both IPv6 addresses and port numbers in URLs use the `:` the address part has to be surrounded with `[` and `]`. For example:

```
http://[2001:db8:1234::abcd]/
```

or if you have to specify a port number:

```
http://[2001:db8:1234::abcd]:8080/
```

Comment: Could you add how I could find this usable IPV6 address?

Comment: That's a bit difficult... It might be shown in the user interface of the router (so you'd have to log in over IPv4 to find the IPv6 address). The nicest would be if the router advertised itself using mDNS/Bonjour/etc. Unfortunately not many routers do that.

Comment: Well I can access the router via speedport.ip, but only as long as I leave the default DNS active. If I change my DNS to Google, which I always do, it does not work anymore. But ok, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue recently.  I found that neither chrome nor Firefox support the scope ID necessary in a link local ipv6 address.  *Lynx* does, but didn't handle the JavaScript needed for logging in to the particular machine I was connecting to.

I managed to work around this with `socat` which supports scope ID.  This command proxies traffic from a localhost ipv4 address to a link local ipv6 address.

`socat TCP4-LISTEN:8080, fork TCP6:[fe80::01%wlo1]:80`

```
localhost proxy port: 8080
ipv6 address of remote machine: fe80::01
port of login page on remote machine: 80
scope ID of local machine: wlo1
```

Leaving this command running in a shell, I was able to navigate to the ipv6 machine's login page with Firefox and Chrome at the proxied address 127.0.0.1:8080

Answer (score 0):

Using your link-local gateway address after stripping the the "%" and interface code at the end should definitely work. In effect, your correct router IPv6 address is:

http://[fe80::1]

The square brackets around the address are necessary for the URL to work.

I tested my router's IPv6 link-local gateway address (http://[fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:ef28]) on two old browsers: Opera 54.0, released **way back** in June 2018, and Chrome 68.0.3440.106, released in August 2018. Both browsers allowed me to login successfully, so this method should definitely work. Hope this helps future users.